# React Native: should there be a "production" flag in the NPM install step on the CI?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, jenkins, babeljs

I'm working on a React Native project and I use Jenkins CI to generate Android production builds. My CI configuration first uses the following command to install dependencies before proceeding to generating a JS Bundle and passing that to Android Build:

```
npm install --production
```

I also recently updated my React Native version to 0.57.4 , after which I also needed to switch to the `metro-react-native-babel-preset` (`v0.49.1`). I added that to my `devDependencies` in `package.json` and also updated my .babelrc like so:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ],
  ...
}
```

(as stated here: https://github.com/facebook/metro/tree/master/packages/metro-react-native-babel-preset)

Since then, the task on the CI server fails (but on my local machine its fine), saying `Error: Cannot find module 'metro-react-native-babel-preset'` since the preset is added to `devDependencies` and the `--production` stops `npm` from installing any `devDependencies`

(as stated here  - "https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install" - "With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies").

Should I add the preset in the `dependencies`, change my CI config or is there something different I should do?

Until now the default configuration, i.e:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  ...
}
```

worked fine, but after the React Native update, I started getting errors.

Comment: This is a common problem with npm modules. Some months ago, I has a similar problem with babel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686071/babel-js-file-cant-resolve-babel-runtime-helpers-builtin-classcallcheck   Also, this is not a jenkins question

Comment: is this dependency metro-react-native-babel-preset required to perform the common command for production : npm run build ?? What commands are you executing for production environment?

Comment: This dependency is a babel preset, which means it does some important transpiling. Therefore it definitely needs to run even in a production build (though it needn't be a part of the output bundle)

Comment: So, if this dependency is required to build, it must be in dependencies sections but is in devDependencies. Is this correct? Also, how is added this dependency? npm install -i ....

Comment: As a general practice, babel presets are kept in devDependencies , and so it was added using `npm install --save-dev <dependency>`

Comment: But, when you run your production commands you have an error because this dependency is in devDependencies section and must be in dependencies sections. Is this ok?

Comment: I finally solved the issue by removing the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the `--production` flag